# Extract portions of two lines into one

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I would like a command line that would convert this input:

```
    capability: ESS Privacy ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime (0x0431)
    signal: -68.00 dBm
    last seen: 0 ms ago
    SSID: ENH202.FW
    Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 6.0 9.0 12.0 18.0
```

to this output line:

```
SSID: ENH202.FW  -68.00 dBm
```

This is inspired by the following command that reads available wifi networks:

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | grep SSID
```

which lists all networks by printing each occurence of the the single line containing 'SSID'.  I would like the same scan to give the signal strength of each SSID.

Is there way to use command line tools to get this list with signal strengths included?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are you having trouble with? Provide a [mcve] for us.

Comment: Given the tags you've included, I'd expect to see bash, awk and sed code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sets the value of the variable `st` when the signal line is reached, and then prints it after the SSID line.

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | awk '/signal:/{st=$2$3} /SSID:/{print $0" "st}'
```

Comment: I stand in respectful awe of linux wizards.

Answer (score 1):

The sed command can do it:

```
sed -n -e '/signal:/h' -e '/SSID:/{G;s/signal://;s/\n//;p}' <inputfile>
```

Explanation:

The `-n` flag tells sed not to print lines.

The first `-e` expression finds the line with 'signal:' in it and puts it in the hold space.  The second finds a line with 'SSID:' in it, `G` appends the hold space to this line, `s/signal://` removes the 'signal:' part, and `s/\n//` removes the carriage return.  Finally, `p` tells sed to print the pattern space.

Comment: While this is an ∞ improvement over the code in the question, it is GNU sed specific, so it doesn't work in *BSD, macOS, etc. You can make it compatible at least with BSD and macOS by putting a semicolon after the `p`.